# How to solve JSON data print out in this program?

Tags: json, go

I am trying to convert data through api url into JSON data. As a whole it works, but when I want to get specific data set from JSON (here I am trying MyStruct which is a data set having name, duration, listners), so it comes with blank result. On the other side, same problem with html template which does not give any result when I call it through local host port.
I have declared a global instance to call data set in template function (could also use in my get content function though) but having fail result.
I am wondered why data variable in get_content having blank result?

```
// created structurs example
type MyStruct struct {
    Name       string
    Duration   string
    and so on..
}
var data1 MyStruct

// function to retreive api data & convert into json.
func get_content() {
    // json data
    url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands"
    url += "" // limit data for testing
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var data MyStruct
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        get_content()
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/", template1)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func template1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fp := path.Join("index.html")
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(fp)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, data1); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

on index file I have written names to call the data:

```
{{.Name}}
{{.Duration}}
{{.Listeners}}
```

Comment: The json for that url starts with `{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Hello","duration":"0", ...`. The corresponding go struct passed in to json.Unmarshal must have a similar structure.

Comment: thanks to reply. Yes, I have the Complete Code which is a Little  bit longer so that I want to focus on the fail result (blank) because I have to print out a specific data set. So in MyStruct it holds variables (name, duration, listeners, mbid and url respectively)

Comment: Other note, you're registering multiple handler for `/`. This is not allowed. Your real code looks the same?

Comment: yes, it looks the same. Infact, I am new to golang but trying to learn it. I have to print out different data sets for example I have different type structures hold different variables to present JSON data. So, I tried to write functions and call these structures into them. I am worried that it can be fail but wondering how to resolve ! (I can share the Whole code if you would like to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a bit more explicit, the go data structure must match the json data structure. Not just the individual 'track', but the entire json structure.

Here's an example based on the response from the url you gave. The response is reduced to fit here, the full response is on the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VcLaaoY6IVb).

The names returned by the json structure are misleading, but it's workable.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Track struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Duration string `json:"duration"`
    //... etc
}

type Data struct {
    Content struct {
        Tracks []Track `json:"track"`
    } `json:"tracks"`
}

func main() {
    var body = []byte(`{
        "tracks":{
            "track":[
                {
                    "name":"Hello",
                    "duration":"123",
                    "listeners":"373721",
                    "mbid":""
                }
            ]
        }
    }`)

    var data Data
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, track := range data.Content.Tracks {
        fmt.Printf("Track: %s\n", track.Name)
    }
}
```

Replacing `body` with the full json (eg, from the url response) and running this prints:

`Track: Hello
Track: Can't Feel My Face
Track: Sultans of Swing
Track: Sorry
Track: Lean On (feat. MØ & DJ Snake)
Track: The Less I Know the Better
Track: Africa
...`

Comment: thanks @Mark ! But I am getting stuck again when I try to create more type structure (same way as you did) but program ends suddenly without any output on terminal. Like:

type Attr_info struct {
   Country    string `json:"country"`
   Page       string `json:"page"`
   PerPage    string `json:"perpage"`
   TotalPages string `json:"totalpages"`
   Total      string `json:"total"`
}

type Data2 struct {
   Content2 struct{
      Attrs[] Attr_info `json:"attr_info"`
   }
}

Comment: (New) thanks @Mark ! But I am getting stuck again when I try to create more type structure (same way as you did) but program ends suddenly without any output on terminal. I have put my work on golang link (i could not put the data because of error from the site)
https://play.golang.org/p/guufCoG4uN7

Comment: You're on the right track (no pun intended...)! Here's another [play](https://play.golang.org/p/HL2dPKc8pDA) showing nested structs. It's worth spending time on the [json.Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) docs.